# Salesforce (Some Applications) down Globally!!! FYI

Tags: trailhead

Unable to login for past 1 hr. Even Login button not working, anyone experiencing same?
[image: Screenshot of trailblazer Site down]

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce is experiencing a massive outage right now. From https://help.salesforce.com/home

> Multiple Salesforce Applications Disrupted
>
> At 21:46 UTC on May 11, 2021, The Salesforce Technology team became aware of an issue impacting multiple Salesforce services. Customers will experience issues while navigating multiple Salesforce services, including the Core application, Marketing Cloud, Commerce Cloud, Government Cloud, and Experience Cloud (fka Communities).
>
> The issue is also impacting the Salesforce Trust site as status.salesforce.com is not currently accessible.
>
> Salesforce is all hands on deck for this incident and exploring multiple paths to resolution. The root cause investigation also continues as the Technology teams are looking at the possibility of a block implemented by a third-party DNS provider, as well as any recent network changes.

Answer (score 1):

Found this article : Which mentioned
Salesforce is disrupted GLOBALLY
many of sites and Clouds are currently down.
So far no ETA declared.
Hopefully we get some response from Salesforce Team.

[image: Tweets from Executives about the Salesforce site disruption]https://techau.com.au/its-not-just-you-salesforce-is-down-globally/